# Find the fallacy in using the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=k$, wherein $f(x),a,b,k$ are positive. According to the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality:

$\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}x^{2}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx\leq
\left (  \int_{a}^{b}x^{4}dx\right )^{0.5}
\left ( \int_{a}^{b}\left (\frac{f(x)}{x}  \right )^{2}dx \right )^{0.5}$,

which implies

$\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx<
\left (  \int_{a}^{b}x^{4}dx\right )^{0.5} \int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=
k\left (  \int_{a}^{b}x^{4}dx\right )^{0.5}=U$.

On the other hand:

$k=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{x^2}xf(x)dx\leq
\left (  \int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{x^4}dx\right )^{0.5}
\left (\int_{a}^{b}\left( xf(x)   \right)^2dx\right )^{0.5},$

which means that

$\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx>\left (\int_{a}^{b}\left( xf(x)   \right)^2dx\right )^{0.5}\geq
k\left (  \int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{x^4}dx\right )^{-0.5}=L$

To sum up:
\begin{align} L=k\left (  \int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{x^4}dx\right )^{-0.5}<\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx<k\left (  \int_{a}^{b}x^{4}dx\right )^{0.5}=U \end{align}

If $[a,b]=[1,2]$, $U=\sqrt{\frac{31}{5}}k>\sqrt{\frac{24}{7}}k=L$: OK

But if $[a,b]=[0.5,1]$, $U=\sqrt{\frac{31}{160}}k<\sqrt{\frac{3}{7}}k=L$, meaning that the upper-bound is smaller than the lower-bound!

In what step I am making a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is off:
$$\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx<
\left (  \int_{a}^{b}x^{4}dx\right )^{0.5} \int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx.$$
It should be (as you previously written, maybe it's just a copypaste error)
$$\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx\leq
\left (  \int_{a}^{b}x^{4}dx\right )^{0.5}
\left ( \int_{a}^{b}\left (\frac{f(x)}{x}  \right )^{2}dx \right )^{0.5}.$$

Now, there're some inequalities allowing to compare $L_1$ and $L_2$ norm on a compact, but it definitely involves some power of $(b-a)$.

Comment: It was not a typo. As you know, Frobenious norm is smaller than the first entry-wise norm. So I think I am allowed to use the first equation you mentioned. Am I wrong?

Comment: For example: $(1^2+2^2)^{0.5}<1+2$

Comment: I don't quite get why you mention Frobenius/element-wise norms, because they are matrix norms, here we talk about norms in Lebesgue spaces.

Comment: I think I get your point. You mean that it is wrong to generalize that rule to Lebesgue spaces?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong to do that. In fact, the embedding of different functional spaces in another and comparing different norms is a huge area of research, take, for example, Sobolev embeddings.

Answer (score 1):

It is not about Cauchy-Schwarz, this is not true: $ (\int_a^b(\frac{f(x)}{x})^2dx)^{0.5}<\int_a^b\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$. Take for instance, $f(x)=x$ and $0<(b-a)<1; a,b>0$.